# TabControl with horizontal and VerticaltabStrip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking for a way to get one vertical Tab header and the other ones sould be rotated on the left Side, because they are created dynamically

When all the Tab headers are set onto the vertical positions it works very welll  But If I want to change their oritentation it doesn't work anymore.

```
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="5000"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

    </TabControl>
```

I know their is the TabStrip property but how to manage it for my case?